# if I don't want to give value for all the map of object in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

- if I don't want to provide route table for all the subnets in the virtual
  network then what should I used here because if I run without route
  table then I am getting error. route table id is required in subnet2.

```
│ Missing required argument
│
│ with module.virtual_network["test-vnet"].azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.route-link-subnet["subnet2"],
│ on modules\virtualNetwork\main.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "route-link-subnet":
│ 30: route_table_id = each.value.route_table
│
│ The argument "route_table_id" is required, but no definition was found.
```

i am creating here multiple virtual network with multiple subnets on each vnet.

```
variable "networks" {
      type = map(object({
        resource_group_name = string
        location            = string
        addressSpace        = list(string)
        dnsServers          = optional(list(string))
        subnets = map(object({
          addressPrefix                     = string
          privateEndpointNetworkPolicies    = optional(bool)
          privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies = optional(bool)
          service_endpoints                 = optional(list(string))
          route_table                       = optional(string)
        }))
      }))
    }
```

```
networks = {
  test-vnet = {
    resource_group_name = "testrg"
    location            = "eastus"
    addressSpace        = ["10.229.192.0/20"]
    dnsServers          = ["10.231.18.4"]
    subnets = {
      subnet1 = {
        addressPrefix = "10.229.199.0/24"
        networkSecurityGroups = {
          subnet1-nsg = {
            security_rules = []
          }
        }
        route_table = "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/test-rt"
      }
      subnet2 = {
        addressPrefix                     = "10.229.198.0/24"
        privateEndpointNetworkPolicies    = true
        privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies = true
        service_endpoints = [
          "Microsoft.Storage"
        ]
        networkSecurityGroups = {
          subnet2-nsg = {
            security_rules = []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "route-link-subnet" {
  for_each       = var.subnets
  subnet_id      = module.subnets[each.key].subnet_id
  route_table_id = each.value.route_table
  depends_on = [
    module.subnets,
    azurerm_virtual_network.Virtual_Network
  ]
}
```

Comment: "I am getting error" - what is the **full** error message?

Comment: @Marcin 

 Error: Missing required argument
│
│   with module.virtual_network["test-vnet"].azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.route-link-subnet["subnet2"],
│   on modules\virtualNetwork\main.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "route-link-subnet":
│   30:   route_table_id = each.value.route_table
│
│ The argument "route_table_id" is required, but no definition was found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide `route_table` for `subnet2` in your `var.subnets`.

Comment: I don't want to attach route table to all the subnets hence, I am not giving route_table in subnet 2.

Comment: @Mr.cool You have to. `route_table_id` is required argument, and you can't omit it.

Comment: can we use any function or any condition here so that we can avoid for subnet 2?

Comment: @Mr.cool No. `Required` is actually **Required** and must be provided for each `azurerm_subnet_route_table_association`.

Comment: is there any other way so that I can link route table to specific subnet?

Answer (score 1):

Your input variable's type constraint disagrees with the requirements of `azurerm_subnet_route_table_association`: the `route_table_id` argument is required for that resource, so it isn't valid to assign `null` to it.

If you wish to only declare route table associations for subnets that have a non-null `route_table_id` then you can use a `for` expression with an `if` clause to filter the `var.subnets` value to include only the elements that have route table IDs:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "route-link-subnet" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for k, s in var.subnets : k => s
    if s.route_table != null
  })

  subnet_id      = module.subnets[each.key].subnet_id
  route_table_id = each.value.route_table

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.Virtual_Network
  ]
}
```

With the example above the `for_each` map will only include the subnets that have `route_table` set, and so there will be no resource instance declared at all for the ones that do not have route tables.

Note that this strategy will only be effective if the `route_table` attribute is always known during the plan phase of Terraform, because otherwise Terraform won't be able to decide during planning how many instances of this resource are declared. What you showed in your question would work, where the route table ID is hard-coded into your object, but it would not work if the route table ID were derived from another `resource` block whose remote object hasn't been created yet.